# FFMPEG move source video up inside overlay image frame box

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to put video inside frame box like this one
[image: image frame box]

I tried to use overly filter, but the video edges, were covered by the frame  , I want at least the lower edge of the video to be moved up (e.g 20px or y=-90) to match with the frame inside border, but I didn't know what code to used to change the source video coordinates .
this is my command

```
ffmpeg -y -i source.mp4 -i 480_border.png -filter_complex "overlay=x=0:y=0" effict0.mp4
```

Comment: Show the complete log from your command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you need to do is `scale` the video, then overlay. Also the first stream of overlay is the background so it should be inversed here.

```
ffmpeg -y -i 480_border.png -i source.mp4 -filter_complex "\
[1:v]scale=w=1280:h=720[src];\
[0:v][src]overlay=x=20:y=20[vid]" \
-map [vid] -c:v libx264 -preset slow -c:a copy \
effict0.mp4
```

Just need to scale the video to the right dimensions.

Comment: shortest should remain off. The frame image is one frame long, so shortest=1 will terminate output after one frame.

Comment: ooh ok, alright :), I guess its only needed with color backgrounds

Comment: @DirkV Sorry for late reply I give-up and use Kdenlive to do that , but I still need to script for mass converting , I got this error `Filter scale has an unconnected output` here is the complete command `ffmpeg -y -i 360_border.png -i s.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=w=425:h=281[src];[0:v][1:v]overlay=x=20:y=20[vid]" -map [vid] -c:v libx264 -preset slow -c:a copy effict0.mp4`

Comment: @Salem indeed. i made a small mistake the [1:v] should be replaced by [src]

Comment: Thanks works perfectly [with some errors from my side], please update the answer , `ffmpeg -y -i 360_border.png -i s.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=w=425:h=281[src];[0:v][src]overlay=x=20:y=20[vid]" -map [vid] -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -c:a copy effict0.mp4`   .  BTW   I chose `w=425:h=281`for video size to shrink it to fit inside the transparent box as you suggested , please clarify that .

Comment: @Salam I changed src fix already. Though I don't think the exact scaling measurements are relevant to the solution. Also, you can use  `h=-1` or `w=-1` to automatically set the width or height relative to the given width or height while preserving the input ratio.